# Meteor/SASS: How to import sass partial into package

Tags: css, meteor, sass

I'm trying to import a SASS partial from meteor app in package SASS file.

My meteor app is structured like this

```
lib
    client
        stylsheets
            _colors.sass
packages
    example
        lib
            client
                style.sass
```

Now I need to import the `_colors.sass` into the style.sass of the package. But the import doesn't work:

**_colors.sass**

```
$gray: #ccc
```

**style.sass**

```
@import colors

#something
    color: $gray
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: @import 'colors';

If this doesn't work, you likely need to give it the relative path to the file from style.sass.